# Android Universal Loader get Multiple bitmap

Tags: android, process, bitmap, loader, universal

I want to get multiple Bitmap from url server.
What's wrong in my code?
I just got one bitmap only..

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bm_list = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
TempVo vo = getData();                            
imageLoader.loadImage(url+vo.getFilename0(), new   
SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        bm_list.add(loadedImage); // add list                   
        if(vo.getFilename1() != null && !"".equals(vo.getFilename1())){
             imageLoader.loadImage(url+vo.getFilename1(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    bm_list.add(loadedImage);

                    if(vo.getFilename2() != null && !"".equals(vo.getFilename2())){

                    // Do ...   imageLoader.loadImage(url+vo.getFilename2(), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() /* again job * / {
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {     
bm_list.add(loadedImage);
                                saveBimap3(bm_list, vo);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        saveBimap2(bm_list, vo); // 2
                    }

                }
            });
        } else {
            saveBimap1(bm_list, vo); // 1
        }
    }
});
```

As you see I try to get multiple bitmap, 
however I just get only one bitmap.
I need to do synchronizing job.

When vo.getFilename2() is not null I just run saveBimap3() only not saveBimap1() activating. In my situation, saveBimap1() run first then saveBimap3() executing...

Please give me an advice..

Comment: What you mean you are not getting. is second loadImage call not happening?